# Why is the date in dmesg wrong?

Tags: 16.04

I am often using `dmesg` to monitor the log when a new USB device is attached. I often "tail" it with timestamps using `dmesg -Tw`. However right now the timestamps are wrong.

So for example, here's the date right now:-

```
alan@gort:~$ date
Tue  6 Dec 12:10:59 GMT 2016
```

I just attached a device and note the date:-

```
[Mon Nov 28 02:51:24 2016] hid-generic 0003:16C0:0482.0010: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Teensy Keyboard/Mouse/Joystick] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.2/input1
[Mon Nov 28 02:51:24 2016] hid-generic 0003:16C0:0482.0011: hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Device [Teensy Keyboard/Mouse/Joystick] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.2/input2
[Mon Nov 28 02:51:24 2016] input: Teensy Keyboard/Mouse/Joystick as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.3/0003:16C0:0482.0012/input/input33
[Mon Nov 28 02:51:24 2016] hid-generic 0003:16C0:0482.0012: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.11 Joystick [Teensy Keyboard/Mouse/Joystick] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1.2/input3
```

Why isn't the log output correct?

Comment: The manpage says `Be aware that the timestamp could be inaccurate!  The time source used for the logs is not updated after system SUSPEND/RESUME`. Maybe your system was suspended before?

Comment: Oh! You're right. I suspend all the time. Well done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ridgy](https://askubuntu.com/users/575265/ridgy) posted [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857636/why-is-the-date-in-dmesg-wrong#comment1321401_857636) explaining this, and [the original poster has verified](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857636/why-is-the-date-in-dmesg-wrong#comment1321402_857636) that the explanation is correct:

The manpage (`man dmesg`) says:

> Be aware that the timestamp could be inaccurate! The time source used
> for the logs is not updated after system SUSPEND/RESUME.

Maybe your system was suspended before?

Answer (score 2):

Workaround is journalctl with -k, --dmesg. I am using -k as it is shorter:

```
journalctl -k
```

It will show only kernel messages and correct time.

To show only kernel lines matching phrase:

```
journalctl -kg phrase
```