# Why does the time given by dmesg timestamps differ from the actual time (and output of `date`)?

Tags: server, time, date, dmesg

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

`dmesg` outputs lines like this:

```
[ma mei  8 09:00:16 2017] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC= SRC=140.205.228.53 DST=xx.xxx.xxx.xxx LEN=143 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=111 ID=10224 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=53 DPT=39382 LEN=123
```

which differs from the output of `date`:

```
$ date
ma  8 mei 2017  8:17:05 CEST
```

Is there an explanation for why the timestamps in `dmesg` differ from the actual time?

Comment: what happened when you execute `dmesg -T` ? do you still see the problem?

Comment: @Yaron I believe OP is executing `dmesg -T` to get those timestamps at all

Comment: You will not get an answer on AU for this question. The -T (--ctime) got introduced into Ubuntu with version 2.20 of `util-linux` (https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.20/v2.20-rc1-ChangeLog) . Ask Karel Zak from Redhat or file a bugreport/feature request if you feel this needs to be changed.

Comment: @Rinzwind OP asks only for an explanation. Is it really beyond us to find out what `dmesg` uses as time source and why it's unreliable? Even the man page gives a clue `Be aware that the timestamp could be inaccurate!  The time source used for the logs is not updated after system SUSPEND/RESUME` but I find it is inaccurate (2 minutes off) when the system has not been suspended and only up for an hour or so...

Comment: Are you asking why the format is different, or why the time is in the future? What timezone is set for the system? How much does `TZ=UTC dmesg -T` and `TZ=UTC date` differ?

Comment: I notice that the difference gets bigger the long the system has been up. Running the two commands suggested by muru, The difference is 10 minutes. I get the same result if I don't specify TZ. After a reboot, the difference is only about 10 seconds

Comment: @Zanna yes. I would consider this a question for U+L, not AU since we accept the Linux core utils from upstream. This probably explains it: https://serverfault.com/a/715975 But the question to me seems to be about the formatting of the date, not the date itself(?)

Comment: I guess I feel there could be a better, clearer answer than that, since there's so much interesting stuff about how the kernel knows the time etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the date in dmesg wrong?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857636/why-is-the-date-in-dmesg-wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Workaround is journalctl with -k, --dmesg. I am using -k as it is shorter:

```
journalctl -k
```

It will show only kernel messages and correct time.

To show only kernel lines matching phrase:

```
journalctl -kg phrase
```

Answer (score 0):

This really isn't Ubuntu specific, but seems a reasonable place to put an answer, as this Q has been open a while.  Copy of answer from [server fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/576139/dmesg-time-vs-system-time-time-isnt-correct):

To verify your theory (which, by the way, is sound), execute the following as root:

```
hwclock --show
```

This will show you your hardware clock on the server you are executing the command.

To synchronise your hardware clock with your system-time (which is managed by ntp), run the following command:

```
hwclock --systohc --utc
```

The last argument (--utc) tells hwclock to store the time in hardware clock in coordinated universal time.

Additionally, please keep in mind that man page for dmesg(1) say the following, so the behaviour you are experiencing is documented and valid:

```
   -T, --ctime
          Print human-readable timestamps.

          Be aware that the timestamp could be inaccurate!  The time
          source used for the logs is not updated after system
          SUSPEND/RESUME.
```